# How to get ID from different controllers Yii2?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

[image: **Here is the block diagram for question**]

In the ActiveForm I have model button with Pjax render field after form from the modal button will created. Added a picture for an example. How can I get newly created id (not select added to the database,  need to get the id that comes from this form).

I think I need to set get to button, than with ajax catch this and transfer to my Pjax rendered cell

I tried variations, but unsuccessfully, I cann't fully understand how to implement it. Can anyone help with the solution ?

```
//TwoController
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Formtwo();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            echo 1;
        //maybe here I must to do query ?
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Index GridView**
[image: **Index GridView**]

Comment: A bit hard to understand what are you trying to achieve here.
You have Form1, Form2.
You are trying to create Form2 instance and then after save pass the newly created id to Form1 page?

Comment: Yes, with a little explanation, I need to get the newly created id Form2 into the Form1 cell `form2_id`. Or in the Form1 itself(in _form), or after Form1 created(in index). The main thing is to make a record in the database table Form1. So after creation of the Form1, cell `form2_id` will show us what kind of  Form2(id)(created in modal form)  belongs to Form1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //TwoController
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Formtwo();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            echo $model->id;
        //maybe here I must to do query ?
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

You don't need query. Just use $model->id. It has value after save().

**Update**

It doesn't matter in which controller you are. You get the id of the model saved after save(). Then you can use id attribute. So, you can open modal  form with ajax load. On form2 you register script to ajax post form. Something like this:

```
$("#form :submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: $("#form").attr("action"),
                data: $("#form").serialize(), 
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#modalid").modal("hide")
                    $.pjax.reload({
                        container: "#grid"
                    });
                   $('#Form2_id').val(response); //here you get the id
                },
            })
            return false;
      });
```

Comment: I mean, how can I get than that id in another controller.

Comment: Well, I just saw your edit and picture with grid. First one is with form, second with grid. If you need to update model on the grid(model1), you need to pass it's id to controller2, update it after saving model2, and reload pjax.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correct; you wish that when a user creates an instance of Form2, it is transferred then to create an instance of Form1, and the id of newly created record for Form2, is put in the Form1 _form.
If I did not understand correctly, please explain better :)

In TwoController create action, after creation, you would call the create action of OneContrller:

```
if ($model->save()) {
return \Yii::$app->runAction('/controller/action-name', ['form2_id'=>$model->id]);
```

}

On OneController actionCreate add parameter with default value:

```
public function actionCreate($form2_id=null) {
```

and make sure it is passed to the view (don't forget to make sure you pass it on create.php as well to the _form.

Comment: If I correctly understand. runAction() after save returns to create(_form) Form1 id value into cell form2_id if $form2_id=null. But I didn't understand what you mean to pass in create.php, _form.php. This one $form2_id=null ? I tried couple variations, but unsuccessfully. Model form creating ~2k rows in database ) And if ($model->save()) { echo 1; ignores echo 1 It need to return modal creation if(result == 1) { $(\$form).trigger("reset"); $.pjax.reload({container:'#crtGrid'}); Added picture after Index GridView.

Comment: At the views folder of _form there's also a file called create, which is called from actionCreation to load the file, and does the call to _form with the parameters sent to it. Just make sure the id you send is being passed from the OneController to create.php, and from create.php to _form.